# Is shower trim still installable with a stripped tapped hole on shower valve?

Tags: shower, trim

One of the screws of my Delta shower faucet had to go in at an angle and the screw stripped. The tapped hole provided by the shower valve may be stripped as well. Is the trim still installable without a mounting screw?

[image: Stripped screw from shower trim]

[image]

Comment: Some silicon caulking should stick it on for a quick fix.  A new screw and re-tapping of screw hole for a good fix.

Comment: Take the trim off and take some pictures so we know what we are dealing with.   Also take a picture of just the trim.  First you don't HAVE to use both screws.   Second sometimes you can add a piece of wood somewhere and screw into that.   Or just caulk the entire thing.   You can't tell much from your picture other than you beat the hell out of that screw.

Comment: I grabbed a new shorter screw and re-tapped the hole on the shower valve. Thanks!